# How write a byte array with integer to file encoded in utf8 format

Tags: utf-8

Recently I stumble in  a problem with UTF8. I have been asked to write and read a file in UTF8 encode.  At the first sight i thought that this was very easy,... but was not. 
My problem is that i have to write a binary file that contaians strings and integers or short integers.
To do that I wrote

```
            byte[] BOM  = new byte[] {0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF};
            byte[] Head;
            byte head4[] = new byte[4];
            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {

                    stream.Write( BOM,0, BOM.Length);
                    Byte[] title = utf8.GetBytes("Hello_Abra");
                    stream.Write(title, 0, title.Length);

                    string HeadString = new string('\0', INDEXLength);
                    Head = utf8.GetBytes(HeadString);
                    stream.Write( Head, 0, Head.Length);

                    WriteInt(1258, head4, 0 );  
                    stream.Write( head4, 0, head4.Length);

            }


        public static void WriteInt(int TheInt, byte[] ToArray, int atIndex) 
    {

        for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) 
        {
            byte thebyte = (byte) (TheInt & 0xff);
            ToArray[atIndex+i] = thebyte;
            TheInt = TheInt>>8;
        }
    }
```

when I get the integer value calling the WriteInt function and try to write it to the file, the content of the result file is allways ANSI and  all chars are written in ANSI format.
On the other hand if I write only the string, the risult file content is UTF8 and string are written in 2 bytes UFT8 format.

What's wrong.  It is the correct way to achieve the goal.
Any help is appreciate.

Joss

Answer (score 0):

The raw bytes you extract from your int are not UTF-8 encoded, so they break the decoding process.

You can encode the string representation:

```
Head = utf8.GetBytes("1258".ToString());
stream.Write( Head, 0, Head.Length);
```

And of course BASE-64 would produce a shorter string for larger numbers:

```
WriteInt(1258, head4, 0 );
Head = utf8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(head4));
stream.Write( Head, 0, Head.Length);
```

Comment: thanks Alireza for your answer. I noted that in my head byte array i had wrong UTF8 code ,, but I tried.   On the other hand if I write Base64String converted to UTF8 How can I read this field from binary file and convert back to integer 1258 ??  thanks again

Comment: I really didn't think that far ;-) You can do the process backwards. Assuming you are in the right position inside the stream and since the 4-bytes int is always converted to an 8-bytes Base-64 which are all ASCII characters and equilvalent to one byte in UTF-8: `stream.Read( Head, 0, 8); byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(utf8.GetString(head)); int n = 0; for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) n = (n << 8) + b[i];`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mixing string and non-string data in the same file, you should not be writing a BOM at the front of the file at all.  You can't write a binary number into a UTF-8 encoded text file.  You need to treat the entire file as binary, not as text, and simply encode/decode the individual strings as needed.

You also have the problem of knowing where a UTF-8 encoded string ends.  I suspect you are trying to write a null terminator after it, but you are not doing that.  You can use `stream.WriteByte(0)` for that.

On the other side, reading a null-terminated string from a `FileStream` is difficult.  You have to read the stream one byte at a time into a buffer until you encounter the null, then you can decode the buffer using `UTF8Encoding`.  Not very efficient.

Personally, I would change the null-terminated strings into length-prefixed strings instead.  Then you can use `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` to handle everything for you, eg:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write("Hello_Abra");
        writer.Write(new string('\0', INDEXLength));
        writer.Write(Int32(1258));
    }
}
```

```
string s;
int i;
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        s = reader.ReadString();
        s = reader ReadString();
        i = reader.ReadInt32();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank yoy Remy, I didn't know about the  UTF8 limits /behavior. It seems that your suggestion is right ... I mean.. to remove BOM and use mixed code as you did in your example....But if I do that I suspect that I am not able to write fixed pair elemnts ... I mean a block of [tex+value] [tex+value] [tex+value]  ?? it's correct ??

Comment: Of course you can. In a binary file, you can write whatever you want, as long as you read them in the same order that you write them. In my example, the file consists of `[length+text][length+text][int32]`, but you could have `[type+length+value][type+length+value][type+length+value]` instead (TLV is common in many file formats and protocols).